# How to remove substring from string in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a local storage data i.e, key => BASIC and value=>"mohankumar" and my substring=> 'kumar'. Actually I want to remove substring from the value.
How to achieve this?

Below is my code,

```
var string = localstorage.getItem('BASIC');
var substring = "kumar";
localstorage.removeItem('BASIC');
```

Comment: Open your console. It says `localstorage is undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

- First there is a typo in *localstorage*. Fix that : S is uppercase as *localStorage*
- You need to get the item from storage, modify it and then set it again (Not remove)
- You need to use **String.replace** method to replace the substring with empty string.

  ```
  var string = localStorage.getItem('BASIC');
  localStorage.setItem('BASIC',string.replace(substring,''));
  ```

Comment: Your answer is correct but without explanation, it becomes an incomplete answer.  Do add some explanation to make it look more complete / meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for warning. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1. `localstorage` is defined as `localStorage`
2. You need to set the item again after removing the substring text

To check this code, simply open your browser console and run this block of code. Make sure you already have `BASIC` set at this time before running this code.

```
var string = localStorage.getItem('BASIC');
var substring = "kumar";
string=string.replace(substring,'');
localStorage.setItem('BASIC',string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *remove* the whole storage item to replace the name, just overwrite it.

This illustrates the steps to take:

```
// Set the storage and log it.
const name = 'mohankumar'
localStorage.setItem('BASIC', name)

const storedName = localStorage.getItem('BASIC')
console.log(storedName)

// Replace name and store it.
localStorage.setItem('BASIC', storedName.replace('kumar', ''))
console.log(localStorage.getItem('BASIC'))
```

Also, it should be `localStorage`, *not* `localstorage` (capitalized S).

Here's a live example on JSFiddle you can play with: https://jsfiddle.net/wppq6o3m/7/